# F#: Using a DU to limit types for a Property

Tags: .net, f#

I am implementing a type that mimics the [System.Data.Common.DbParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  This type will be used across C#,VB.NET,and F# projects. Here is a slimmed down example:

```
type myNewType =
   member val Direction: int = 0 with get,set
   member val Value: Object = null with get,set
```

The [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the class is of type object.  In my type, I want to limit that property to either a string or a byte array.  I was thinking that a DU might be perfect but I am unsure of the syntax.  Here is some psudo code:

```
type Value =
| Value of String or byte[]

type myNewType =
   member val Direction: int = 0 with get,set
   member val Value: Value = [||] with get,set
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type DbParameterValue = 
| StringValue of s: string
| BytesValue of bytes: byte[]

type myNewType() = 
  member val Direction = 0 with get, set
  member val Value: DbParameterValue = BytesValue([||]) with get, set
```

the member val syntax always trips me up. The hardest part is figuring out a good default value.  I'd say that an empty byte array isn't ideal here at all, perhaps take a constructor parameter to set what the initial state should be?

Answer (score 4):

When you are using a DU you have to explicitly spell out the alternatives you want to employ

Try something like the below

```
type Value =
| StringVal of string
| ByteVal of byte[]
| Initial

type myNewType =
    member val Direction: int = 0 with get,set
    member val Value: Value = Initial with get,set
```

Where `Initial` would be used as a sort of default.

Answer (score 4):

From an F# perspective, it seems like you can model your domain best by using two Discriminated Unions, one for direction and one for value.

```
type Direction =
    |Input
    |InputOutput
    |Output
    |ReturnValue

type Value =
    |String of string
    |Bytes of byte[]
```

Then combine them in your `DBParameter` type.  I would recommend record syntax for this:

```
type DBParameter = {Direction : Direction; Value : Value}
```

Then you could create an instance like this:

```
let dbParam = {Direction = ReturnValue; Value = String "Some return value"}
```

You will need to consider how the discriminated unions will be consumed in other .NET languages.  For this purposes, referring to  [section 5.1](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#51-namespace-and-type-design-for-libraries-for-use-from-other-net-languages) of component design guidelines will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The acronym "DU" stands for "Discriminated Union". That is, it's a union of types in which you can *discriminate* between them. The "*discriminate*" part is important here. It means that each type in the union is "tagged" with a special label, and you can use these labels to tell which type it is.

```
type Value = StringValue of string | ByteValue of byte[]
```

To create values of this type, you specify which case you mean:

```
let v1 = StringValue "abc"
let v2 = ByteValue [|1b;2b;3b|]
```

When you got a value from somewhere, you can use the labels to determine which kind of value you got:

```
match v with
| StringValue s -> printfn "Got a string: %s" s
| ByteValue a -> printfn "Got %d bytes" a.Length
```

Some languages have "undiscriminated unions". For example, in TypeScript you can do this:

```
type T = string | number;
var x : T = 5;
x = "abc"
if ( typeof x === "string" ) return x.length;
```

F# doesn't have those.